# How to show a progress bar while sending an ajax request in Sencha Touch?

Tags: ajax, extjs, sencha-touch-2.1

In my Sencha Touch Application, I make an Ajax Request. I want to show a progress bar while the request is being processed and it set a timeout of 60 seconds. If the connection is timeOut, then I want to display a msg "The connection is slow". How to do it? Following is the code of Ajax Request.

```
  $.ajax(
               {
                     type : "GET",
                     async : false,
                     dataType : "text",
                     url : 'someurl',
                     success : function(data1)
                     {


                     }
          });
```

How to modify the code to add the above functionalities??

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
var basePanel = 
Ext.ComponentQuery.query("toppanel")[0];
var loginFormPanel = 
Ext.ComponentQuery.query("loginformpanel")[0];

var task = Ext.create('Ext.util.DelayedTask', function() {
Ext.Viewport.mask({ xtype: 'loadmask',
                   message: "Checking Credentials.." });
}, this);

task.delay(500);

// do login and if success, 
//   flip, otherwise show error
Ext.Ajax.request({
url:'/rpc/Account/Login', 
params: {
    Username: loginFormPanel.getValues().username,
    Password: loginFormPanel.getValues().password,
    RememberMe: loginFormPanel.getValues().rememberMe != null
},
success: function(response){
    task.cancel(); 
    Ext.Viewport.unmask(); 
    basePanel.animateActiveItem(1,{type: 'flip' });
},
failure: function() {
    task.cancel(); 
    Ext.Viewport.unmask(); 
    Ext.Msg.alert("Login Failed");
}
});
```